# How to make layout just for selected nodes inside compound(parent) nodes?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have 3 compound(parent) nodes. In every compound node there are 3 child nodes. I want the layout to be exactly like this:

```
COMPOUND1     COMPOUND2     COMPOUND3
node1.type1   node4.type2   node4.type3
node2.type1   node4.type2   node4.type3  
node3.type1   node4.type2   node4.type3
```

so I want to have 3 compound nodes in one row and in each of them one column of nodes each on top of each other. There are edges between different child nodes but I guess this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid layout: http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/grid

Specify the columns for the child nodes.  If you don't set rows, the rows will be automatic.

Compound parents are always automatically positioned for you.

Comment: hello @maxkfranz, thanks for reply, I've tried this but there is a strange behavior: when you put different number of child nodes per on compound node, then the compound nodes change its place. So for example I want 2 child nodes in Compound1 and 4 nodes in Compound2, then the order is not Compound1, Compound2, Compound3 but something else..

Comment: The positions of the parents are based on the children.  Set your child positions appropriately for the effect you want.

Comment: @maxkfranz is there a way to apply grid layout for component nodes, like splitting columns inside a component nodes,